# GeoPandas equivalent of ST_MakePolygon

Tags: geopandas

What is the GeoPandas equivalent of `ST_MakePolygon`?

I want to convert a MULTIPOLYGON to one single polygon. Currently, using GeoPandas.boundary a `MultiLineString` is returned.

How can this one be converted to a regular `POLYGON`?
As far as I understand `ST_MakePolygon` would be the post GIS pendant.

## edit

I am aware of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2964751/how-to-convert-a-geos-multilinestring-to-polygon-using-python, i.e. `convex_hull`, but this only returns a rather distorted geometry.

I.e. in case one looks at the shape of Austria this is:
[image]

### edit2

A `df.explode()` will convert the `MULTIPOLYGON` to `POLYGON`.

Some answers suggest to aggregate via `dissolve`, however:

```
type(df(by='column_with_constant_value', aggfunc='sum').iloc[0].geometry)
```

still is

```
shapely.geometry.multipolygon.MultiPolygon
```

The same for:

```
type(df.cascaded_union)
shapely.geometry.multipolygon.MultiPolygon
```

### edit3

The Polygon I am looking at is the Austrian borders from GADM. https://biogeo.ucdavis.edu/data/gadm3.6/gpkg/gadm36_AUT_gpkg.zip is the download link.

- unzip it
- `df = gp.read_file()`

The distorted image looks like:
[image]

Comment: Try: `somedf.geometry = somedf.geometry.apply(lambda x: list(x)[0])`. See: [How to extract Polygons from Multipolygons in shapely?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38930192/how-to-extract-polygons-from-multipolygons-in-shapely).

Comment: This distorts the geoemtry. Do note that: `df.explode` already does this and returns a list of polygons. However, then as a next step I need to get them combined into a single polygon.

Comment: Add a screenshot of your polygon please. Or even better a reproducible example polygon.

Comment: done -see the latest edit

Comment: Your polygon is in fact a multipart polygon consisting of two parts. Your added screenshot is one of the two parts, the other part is much bigger and looks like austria and is touching by the Southern tip of your screenshot polygon. So it is not possible to convert the two non-overlapping parts into one single part polygon.

Comment: But they touch? So why can't they be combined? Or atleast their single shared boundary be used to create a new single polygon with same extent?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your polygon is in fact a multi-polygon constisting of two parts:

[image]

They are intersecting(/touching borders?) in one point:

```
part1, part2 = polys.geometry.apply(lambda x: list(x))[0]
part1.intersects(part2)
True
```

But it does not seem to be possible to convert them into one single part. I assume they need to overlap, not only touch borders in one point as you would create a self-intersecting polygon.

You can try creating a small buffer polygon at the intersection point to connect the two parts and then dissolve the three polygons:

```
polygons = polys.geometry.apply(lambda x: list(x))[0]
polygons.append(polygons[0].intersection(polygons[1]).buffer(0.0001))
polys.geometry = [unary_union(polygons)]

polys.geometry.type
0    Polygon
dtype: object

polys.plot(cmap='cool')
```

[image]